# export <svg> in pdf with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, php, css, svg, wkhtmltopdf

I use phpwkhtmltopdf by mike haertl (https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)
Everything works perfectly and easily.. but I have a HUGE issue. I can export an `<img>` that plays a .svg but I can't export an `<svg>`.

For example:

here is the kind of "raw" .svg I receive from the graphic department.

[image]

Then to turn .svg to `<svg>` I use that javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
        jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
                if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                    $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
                }

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

            }, 'xml');   
        });
    });
    </script>
```

As a result I get something like this :

[image]

This allow me to add the stylesheet to layers. I.E

```
<style type="text/css">
svg #GRILLE-1 * {stroke: darkgrey; stroke-width:2px; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;shape-rendering: crispedges;}
svg #GRILLE-2 * {stroke: lightgrey; stroke-width:1px; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;shape-rendering: crispedges;}
svg #GRILLE-TEXT text {font-size: 10px;
font-family: sans-serif;
fill: grey;
}
svg #GRILLE-DASH * {stroke: grey; stroke-width:1px; stroke-dasharray: 5,5;}
svg #VISUEL-1 * {stroke: black; stroke-width:3px;fill:none;}
svg #VISUEL-2 * {stroke: grey; stroke-width:2px;fill:none;}
svg #VISUEL-3 * {stroke: lightgrey; stroke-width:2px;fill:none;}
</style>
```

On the intranet I have no problem to display the good result. On Chrome's webkit as well :

[image]

**So my problem is when I export in pdf through wkhtmltopdf I get the same result than the "raw" file.** If I directly go to the url of the page I export, everything displays fine...

[image]

I have no idea what to do and where to begin to solve that issue.

---

### EDIT

ROOT (/pdf/_demo/):

```
    require 'file:///Users/************/vendor/autoload.php' ;
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;


$pdf = new Pdf(array(
    'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
    'ignoreWarnings' => true,
    'no-outline',         // Make Chrome not complain
    'margin-top'    => 0,
    'margin-right'  => 0,
    'margin-bottom' => 0,
    'margin-left'   => 0,
    'page-size' => 'A4',
    //'width'         => 960,
    //'dpi' => 248,
    'dpi' => 248,
    'javascript-delay' => 3000,

    // Default page options
    'disable-smart-shrinking',
    //'user-style-sheet' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pdf/_demo/lapis/pdf.css',

));

        $content1 = '*****/pdf/_demo/contenu/contenu-1.php';
        $content2 = '*****/pdf/_demo/contenu/contenu-2.php';



        $pdf->addPage($content1);
        $pdf->addPage($content2);

        if (!$pdf->saveAs('rendus/'.$n.'.pdf')) {
            echo $pdf->getError();
        }

        echo 'succès';
```

And content1 (/pdf/_demo/contenu/contenu-1.php)

```
<style type="text/css">
svg #GRILLE-1 * {stroke: darkgrey; stroke-width:2px; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;shape-rendering: crispedges;}
svg #GRILLE-2 * {stroke: lightgrey; stroke-width:1px; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;shape-rendering: crispedges;}
svg #GRILLE-TEXT text {font-size: 10px;
font-family: sans-serif;
fill: grey;
}
svg #GRILLE-DASH * {stroke: grey; stroke-width:1px; stroke-dasharray: 5,5;}
svg #VISUEL-1 * {stroke: black; stroke-width:3px;fill:none;}
svg #VISUEL-2 * {stroke: grey; stroke-width:2px;fill:none;}
svg #VISUEL-3 * {stroke: lightgrey; stroke-width:2px;fill:none;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>


 <img class="svg" src="/pdf/_demo/contenu/test.svg">

 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
        jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
                if(!$svg.attr('viewBox') && $svg.attr('height') && $svg.attr('width')) {
                    $svg.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + $svg.attr('height') + ' ' + $svg.attr('width'))
                }

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

            }, 'xml');   
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you share the entire html

Comment: @mdeora see edits below. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to check but I fixed mine* with style="fill:transparent;" somehow the default svg fill is different in wkhtmltopdf.

[polygon-looking polyline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8z8v.png)

*my polyline graph looked like a polygon
after the transparent fill

[polyline with transparent fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5tvn.png)